# How does one return the object values only from each object of an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, javascript-objects, return-value

So I am running a NodeJS Serverless instance, using Knex.js as my DB middleware. When attempting to return JUST the value from a request to Knex, I always get `[ { vrn: 'xx12xyz' } ]`. I have tried using Object(), does anyone have a quick one liner or small helper function that can help me flatten this into a direct array such that I can pick out JUST the value?

This is the code I am using:

```
const vrnList = await db('vehicles').select('vrn').where('id', '=', '1');
    console.log("The quick car with the VRN ", Object.values(vrnList), " overtook me on the freeway");
```

TL;DR: Splitting the object and array id from the values

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
let onlyValues = vrnList.map(result => result.vrn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP seems to retrieve the value(s) key agnostic via [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) which returns an array of values, the OP in addition needs to utilize [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) ...

```
vrnList.flatMap(item => Object.values(item))
```

```js
console.log(
  [ { vrn: 'xx12xyz' } ].flatMap(item => Object.values(item))
);
console.log(
  [
    { vrn: 'xx12xyz' },
    { vrn: 'xx98abc' },
    { vrn: 'yy34xyz' },
  ].flatMap(item => Object.values(item))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: All fixed - Thank you. I was left with an array but using the `toString()` function fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @JPA ... maybe the OP considers giving an own answer of how the problem got solved. I personally doubt that a `toString` on the provided data structure actually was the only thing needed in order to fix all issues.

Comment: No what I meant was that your answer, partnered with toString(), made it work

Comment: @JPA ... *"No what I meant was that your answer, partnered with toString(), made it work"* ... good to hear. And at SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.